# Why is my readline() not appending to my list?

Tags: python

I am trying to open a file and append the items onto a list named Apple_data. Variable explorer shows that my list is empty, so whenever I try to print it only [] shows up. I also keep getting an error that says "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'readline'."

I tried changing my code after the for loop to stock = stock.rstrip('\n') and the function reads the file but does not append to the list still.

How do I fix this?

```
def read_file(Apple_stock):
 
    Apple_stock = open("ApplePrices.txt", "r")
    Apple_data = []
    
    for stock in Apple_stock:
        stock = Apple_stock.readline().rstrip('\n')
        Apple_data.append(stock)
    Apple_stock.close()
    return Apple_data
    print(Apple_data)
```

Comment: try Apple_stock.readline() rather than Apple_data.readine()

Comment: Can you elaborate as to how you reached the conclusion that your `Apple_data` variable *should* have an instance method called `readline()`? What exactly do you expect this method to do when called on a `list` object?

Comment: Typo in readline. Voting to close.

Comment: Hi Monique, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question has become a bit confused, as it seems like you have had several issues and it's not clear which of them you've already fixed and which ones are still represented in the code you're showing us. The main issue seems to be that you're getting an empty list out? Nothing I see in your code matches up with that. Can you show how you're calling your `read_file` function?

Answer (score 1):

Apple_data is your list. you cannot call `readline` on it as its a list not a file. You also dont need to call readline as your already iterating over your file line by line in your for loop so you just need to do

```py
def read_file(Apple_stock):
 
    Apple_stock = open("ApplePrices.txt", "r")
    Apple_data = []
    
    for stock in Apple_stock:
        Apple_data.append(stock.rstrip())
    Apple_stock.close()
    return Apple_data
    print(Apple_data)
```

you could also probably clean it up a bit more using a context manager to handle the file closuer and a list comprehension to generate your list

```py
def read_file(stock_data):
    with open(stock_data) as stocks:
        return [stock.rstrip() for stock in stocks.readlines()]

print(read_file("ApplePrices.txt"))
```